# Keep parallax fixed but change image on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax, scrolltop

I have a div where I want to change the image and text when I scroll on it. I have gotten some of the way but I cant figure out how to keep the "parallax-row" fixed, but act like its scrolling? I have a code pen link to help below.
MY GOAL : When you scroll anywhere in the parallax-window everything should stick, but the image and text changes. I have seen some cool image effects using parallax so thats why I am learning it.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/lacheporter/pen/JjWRWQv)

```
<html>
<body>
  <!---------PARALLAX------->
  <div class="parallax-window">
    <div class="parallax-container">
      <div class="parallax-row">
        <div class="parallax-image-container">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/18/19/07/happy-1836445_1280.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="parallax-text">
          <h1>Title 1</h1>
          <h3>This is a description.
          </h3>
          <div class="mouseicon">
            <div class="mousewheel"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*PARALLAX */
.parallax-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.parallax-window {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
.parallax-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
.parallax-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
.parallax-image-container {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
}
.parallax-image-container img {
  height: inherit;
}
.parallax-text {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0em 4em;
}
.mouseicon {
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 65px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.mousewheel {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  animation: scroll 1.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
}
```

JS

```
//-------PARALLAX SCROLL-------- //
const parallaxContainer = document.querySelector(".parallax-window");
const parallaxImage = document.querySelector(".parallax-image-container img");
parallaxContainer.scrolltop = 0;
const parallaxText = document.querySelector(".parallax-text h1")

var scrollHandler = function () {
  var newImageUrl = parallaxImage.src;

  var scrollTopParallax =
    parallaxContainer.scrollTop || parallaxContainer.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTopParallax > 100) {
    newImageUrl =
      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/07/16/balancing-1868051__480.jpg";
    parallaxText.innerHTML = "Title 2"
  }
  if (scrollTopParallax < 100) {
    newImageUrl =
      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/18/19/07/happy-1836445_1280.jpg";
    parallaxText.innerHTML = "Title 1"
  }

  parallaxImage.src = newImageUrl;
  console.log("new: " + parallaxImage.src);
};
parallaxContainer.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my codepen with my own answer. essentially creating an overlay to scroll on and then changing the elements based on that invisible overlays scroll position. see link to codepen above.